# UITableViewCell with custom UIButton as subview: CAGradientLayer of button not displayed

Tags: uitableview, uibutton, calayer

slight problem i'm having with my custom UIButton subclass when added to the contentView of a UITableViewCell. basically, the button class adds a CAGradientLayer in its constructor to create a glossy background:

```
CALayer *layer = self.layer;
layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height/6;
layer.masksToBounds = YES;
layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;  
layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 
                                  green:0.0 
                                   blue:0.0 
                                  alpha:.75].CGColor;    
CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.4f].CGColor,
                      (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.2f].CGColor,
                      (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.75f alpha:0.2f].CGColor,
                      (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.4f alpha:0.2f].CGColor,
                      (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.4f].CGColor,
                      nil];
gradientLayer.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],
                         [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5f],
                         [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5f],
                         [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8f],
                         [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f],
                         nil];
gradientLayer.frame = self.layer.bounds;
[self.layer addSublayer:gradientLayer];
```

this works great everywhere in the app except for when i just tried to add this button as a subview of a UITableViewCell:

```
myButton = [[MyButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[self.contentView addSubview:oddsButton];
```

And laid out in layoutSubviews:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGRect rect;
    rect.size.height = 30;
    rect.size.width = 60;
    rect.origin.x = self.frame.size.width - rect.size.width - 20;
    rect.origin.y = self.frame.size.height/2 - rect.size.height/2;
    myButton.frame = rect;
}
```

The button displays fine, but the layer is not displayed at all - i just get a rectangular plain coloured button. i've also tried manually resizing the layer in layoutSubviews, but this makes no difference. this would seem to suggest that all the quartz drawing is ignored on the table view cell. as an alternative, i considered adding the gloss as a subview of the button, and this works but is displayed on top of the button's normal views/labels/etc so doesn't quite seem ideal.